# Unable to get a whole shipping address in magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I'm trying to get a shipping Address as whole like in the table `sales_order_grid` I had tried like below,

```
public function getordetails($orderid){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);

        $total = $order->getGrandTotal();        

        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();   


        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();   

        $telephone = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();         

        $address =  $shippingAddress->getStreet();  

        $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();

        return $address;

    }
```

But here only able to get separated.. Is anyother way to get a like a whole address like in the table `sale_order_grid`  Please Anyone help me Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet hope it will work:

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$Address = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender‌​\OrderSender');

$Address-‌​>getFormattedBilling‌​Address($order); 
$Address->getFormattedShippingAddress($orde‌​r);
```

Also you can try this ( which will return an array:

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
```

Comment: here $order is a entity_id.??

Comment: here $order is object, which you already getting : $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);

Comment: i had received this error  `Class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender‌​\OrderSender does not exist`

Comment: did you tried other one ?  $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();

Comment: remove starting "\" from "\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender‌​\OrderSender". i will be updating code too.

Comment: Again same error `(ReflectionException): Class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender‌​\OrderSender does not exist `

Comment: strange, could you try other line of code. ( for me both are working )

Comment: my magento version is 2.2.2 what is your version

Comment: can you please share full controller file that you tried on yourself

Comment: i have same version